# How can I stop running application in backgournd and exit without exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have many winforms in a project. When I click on Cross button to close one specific form maybe it is running in the background process. So How can I stop that from running in background when I click on cross button. I have the code for exiting application;

```
Application.Exit();
```

But this also shows exception when from *frmMainMenu*  I click on logoutMenuStrip option. For the LogoutMenuStrip I have the following code to forcefully exit the application. But still it shows some exception. My Question is how can I Prevent all exception when I click on that logoutMenuStrip.

> I supposed that maybe on clicking the other forms closing they get
>   running in background

Code for LogoutMenuStrip:

```
private void logoutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to QUIT ?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            Application.Exit();
        }
        catch
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: maybe you should show the part where you run something in the background instead ... your forms should never throw exceptions when they are closed!

Comment: Please define how are are using forms 'running in background'.. what is exactly means. Are you using and background worker thread, threading, parallel tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple instances of your application running and one or more of those is in background, you can enumerate the processes and then kill them.

```
var processes=Process.GetProcessByName( "AppName" );
foreach(var process in processes )
    process.Kill();
```

Answer (score 1):

use Environment.Exit(0); it closes everything and shuts down your application

```
    private void logoutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to QUIT ?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Thorarins. This solution also works. But I prefered process killing;

Comment: This is the cleaner solution though; it's just asking the app to close rather than forcing it.